# Validations in multistep wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im trying to setup validations on a multistep wizard (using the wicked gem and this [GUIDE](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Partial-Validation-of-Active-Record-Objects)). The first step I am entering some user information (using Devise + Registrations) but when I submit that I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#create

undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/remindeal1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:54:in `active_or_address?'


Class User
  validates_presence_of :address, :presence => true, :if => :active_or_address?

  def active_or_address?
    status.include?('address') || active?
  end

 def active?
   status == 'active'
 end
```

Comment: Where is 'status' declared? It's nil, so you can't call functions of it, right? Or is that variable included somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add 'status' to the User model and from the wizard controller set it to the value of step.

The guide instructs you to perform the migration in the beginning of the 'Solution' section:

```
class ProductStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    add_column :products, :status, :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column :product, :status
  end

end
```